# Is the second Open Mic Nite open in the Auditorium?

Tags: discussion, chat, event

Is the Open Mic Nite happening right now? Again?

(note to dup script: this is a different one than the last question)

Answer (score 1):

*Edit:* Closed again. Next one in 2 weeks, on or about the 30th of March.

*Earlier:*
Yes, it started [mere moments ago](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/60655132#60655132) and will run for 24 hours (at least).